# Java Generic type inference derived from method return type

Tags: java, generics, javac, type-inference, eclipse-jdt

```
public class TestCase {
    public static String compiles() {
        return getAction();
    }

    /*
    public static String doesntCompile1() {
        return (String) getAction();
    }

    public static String doesntCompile2() {
        return TestCase.<String> getAction();
    }
    */

    public static <T extends javax.swing.Action> T getAction() {
        return (T) null;
    }
}
```

Should this be considered a bug in javac v1.6.0_22 and jdt v3.7.1?  To me it seems that way since in the other cases, the compiler actually finds the potential ClassCastException.  In the compiles method, this will throw at ClassCastException at runtime.

The original code that brought this exemple didn't compile in javac, printing the following exception.  Unfortunately, the exemple code I provided for some reason will not generate this error.

```
type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined;
no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds
```

Comment: I'am not getting your question

Comment: So the original code not shown had a syntax error? What is the question?

Comment: The code as is compiles but throws `ClassCastException` at run-time. I think OP's question is why compiler cannot deduce that, which it can in the second (commented out) case.

Comment: Let's wait if someone else's knows the answer.

Comment: I am very surprised by the fact that the first method compiles...

Comment: @MiserableVariable This is indeed what this code sample points out too.

Comment: @AJG85 the original code would generate the provided compilation error in javac.  Like i said, i don't know exactly what provokes javac to determines this as an error in some cases and not so in others.  In JDT, the compiler never caught any compilation error.

Comment: This compiles fine with javac for me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect a good compiler to be able to detect the error, but as an optimization.  You present a specific case of a more general case like this:

```
public class TestCase {
    public static TypeA methodA() {
        return methodB();
    }

    public static <T extends TypeB> T methodB() {
        return (T) null;
    }
}
```

Now, in general there's nothing wrong with that, provided:

1. If TypeA and TypeB are both classes then TypeB is a superclass of TypeA.
2. TypeA *or one of TypeA's subtypes* inherits from TypeB.

Now the key thing that the compiler *isn't* checking is #2, when it can in this case.  But that is *only* because `String` is a final class.  If the class isn't final, #2 will always be true because the potential subclasses aren't known at compile time.

Imagine that instead of `String`, you used `CharSequence`.  Then I would expect all three to compile.  However, I cannot explain why in your example the second and third method do not compile.

### Edit

And now I have tried it with `javac`, and have found that the first method does not compile either.  The above accepts the premise of your question which seems to be false. I get the misleading compile error

> Incompatible types.  Required: `java.lang.String`.  Found: `T`.

This answer doesn't answer the full question, but rather explains why it doesn't work but something like this:

```
public static CharSequence compiles() {
    return (CharSequence)getAction();
}
```

does.

Comment: I think I understand your answer, but would just like a little clarification.  Why is it that casting the return type in methodA or specificaly typing <TypeA> methodB() would trigger the compiler error?  I am assuming this since I don't have my workstation close by.

Comment: @ebelanger: It *doesn't* trigger the compile error for me; for me all three of the methods you give fail to compile.  However, the first and second methods *do* give different error messages (the second fails because it detects that a `String` can never be an `Action`, while the first fails for what appears to be an inference problem).  I assume that this is a limitation on the inference engine.  If I do `String val = getAction(); return val;` I get the same error as the first which makes me think the limitation is inferring from assignment vs inferring from an expression.

Comment: I think I clearly understand what you are getting to and I thank for for your elaborations.  My last question would be that would it be pertinent to report the compiled method behavior as a bug to the respective compilers?

Comment: @ebelanger: What would you say is the bug?  It doesn't compile, and shouldn't.  Yes it has a hard-to-understand message but maybe that's defined in the JLS.   I would do a bit more research.  If you were going to submit it as a bug, I think a much more interesting case is when you swap out `String` for another interface such as `CharSequence`.  Then the second compiles but the first still doesn't.  Using `String` is a red herring.  If it compiles in the JDT I would report that as a bug to Eclipse; at the very least they'll analyze the case and say whether it conforms to the spec or not.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what the problem/question is here. The errors you are getting are both obvious and expected.

For the `doesntCompile1` method, my compiler tells me

> Cannot cast from Action to String

which is totally expected - we know the method returns a `T` which is an `Action` and we know an `Action` can't be cast to a `String`.

For the `doesntCompile2` method, my compiler tells me

> Bound mismatch: The generic method getAction() of type TestCase is not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

which is basically the same reason as above

What did you expect it to do?

Comment: it's actually the method that compiles that troubles me since this will cause a runtime exception.

Comment: I executed it and it didn't cause an exception for me. I am running standard java 1.6